# Cannot set TabItem text and icon size is always the same size

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically I want to increase the size of the icon and maybe set text instead but I want to set text per `xml` or over the `Tablayout` to the current tab item I don't get anything and can't increase the image size of the tab item ?

How to  make the text visible and how to change size of the icon in `Tabitem` ?

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabsMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_testiranje"
                    android:text="SDSDSDS" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_homeblue"
                    android:text="SDSDSDS" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a style tag to default tab layout by providing its properties like **textSize**, **fontFamily** etc.

```
<style name="TabTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDefault</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>

</style>
```

and use in your **activity/fragment.xml** as

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTheme" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output of Android Tab Layout]